# ForEach for list of list in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, foreach

I am trying to do some operations with list of list.

I have a list with some properties. I have splitted the list into sublists based on GroupId Property.

I am assigning each listitems in the list to another class. but here i had to use 2 ForEachs. is there any way to do it in one so that i can increase the performance when it comes to a large input of more than 10000 list items in the input list. below is the code I tried

```
 class Comp
 {
    public int CompId { get; set; }
    public string CompName { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
 }

 class EmpComp
 {
        public int EmpCompId { get; set; }
        public string EmpCompName { get; set; }
        public int EmpId { get; set; }
        public int GroupId { get; set; }
 }

    #region Input

    List<Comp> compList = new List<Comp>();
    compList.Add(new Comp { CompId = 1, CompName = "One", GroupId = 1 });
    compList.Add(new Comp { CompId = 2, CompName = "Two", GroupId = 1 });
    compList.Add(new Comp { CompId = 3, CompName = "One", GroupId = 2 });
    compList.Add(new Comp { CompId = 4, CompName = "Three", GroupId = 1 });
    compList.Add(new Comp { CompId = 5, CompName = "One", GroupId = 4 });
    compList.Add(new Comp { CompId = 6, CompName = "Two", GroupId = 4 }); 

    #endregion

    var groupedCompList = compList.GroupBy(u => u.GroupId ).Select(grp => grp.ToList()).ToList();
    List<EmpComp> empCompList = new List<EmpComp>();
    int empId = 0;//Just for reference
    groupedCompList.ForEach(x =>
    {
        x.ForEach(y =>
        {
            EmpComp empComp = new EmpComp();
            empComp.EmpCompId = y.CompId;
            empComp.EmpCompName = y.CompName;
            empComp.GroupId = y.GroupId ;
            empComp.EmpId = empId + 1;
            empCompList.Add(empComp);
        });
        empId++;
    });
```

I want to avoid usage of two ForEachs here.

Note: I have some other ids and strings which needs to be assigned based in the GroupId . empId is only an example

Comment: The `ForEach`s will have a negligible impact on performance. However way you code it, you'll still have to do `groupedCompList.Count * x.Count` operations.

Comment: Without ToList it is working faster... List<EmpComp> empCompList = new List<EmpComp>();
compList.GroupBy(u => u.DisplayOrder).ForEach(x => x.ForEach(y =>...));

Comment: As stated by @Rob, you will have to iterate over the two lists - since it will always be the case, why don't you wan't to have two foreach? Anything else will be brittle and more difficult to read for the next developer :-)

Answer (score 3):

There's no need for nested `ForEach`s or even a `SelectMany` as the group that is created is just flatten by the nested `ForEach`s. In fact the current code is incorrect as the `DisplayOrder` property isn't really ordering when a `GroupBy` is called - it just happens that the first value for each distinct `DisplayOrder` is in order in the source data. If it were not the the result would be out of order.

This works without any grouping or use of `ForEach`, and it correctly orders the result:

```
List<EmpComp> empCompList =
    compList
        .OrderBy(u => u.DisplayOrder)
        .Select((y, n) => new EmpComp()
        {
            EmpCompId = y.CompId,
            EmpCompName = y.CompName,
            DisplayOrder = y.DisplayOrder,
            EmpId = n + 1,
        }).ToList();
```

---

Thanks to the comments I realized the original code had the `empId++;` outside the inner loop.

Here's my code that fixes the issue:

```
List<EmpComp> empCompList =
    compList
        .OrderBy(u => u.DisplayOrder)
        .GroupBy(u => u.DisplayOrder)
        .Select((ys, n) =>
            ys
                .Select(y => new EmpComp()
                {
                    EmpCompId = y.CompId,
                    EmpCompName = y.CompName,
                    DisplayOrder = y.DisplayOrder,
                    EmpId = n + 1,
                }))
        .SelectMany(x => x)
        .ToList();
```

This gives this result:

[image: empCompList]

Comment: But the OP code seems to assign an unique `EmpId` per each `DisplayOrder` group key.

Comment: Thts right.. for each DisplayOrder the EmpId is different.

Comment: empId declared in the code is just for reference. Tht may be a property of another object or anything else too

Comment: DisplayOrder is just a property used to group the list nothing else

Comment: @Midhun - But you are doing nothing with that grouping.

Comment: The only intention of grouping is to assign the EmpId and someother properties which is not mentioned here based on the GroupId(I hv changed DisplayOrder to GroupId in the question)

Comment: I have some other ids and strings which needs to be assigned based in the GroupId but those are not mentioned in my question

Comment: @IvanStoev - Good spotting. I can't believe I missed that. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @IvanStoev - I just saw your answer. I've upvoted. :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about like this (tuned Enigmativity's answer):

```
int empId=0;
Dictionary<string, int> displayOrderTable = compList.GroupBy(u => u.DisplayOrder).Distinct().ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, (v,k)=>empId++;)
List<EmpComp> empCompList =
    compList
        .OrderBy(u => u.DisplayOrder)
        .Select((y, n) => new EmpComp()
        {
            EmpCompId = y.CompId,
            EmpCompName = y.CompName,
            DisplayOrder = y.DisplayOrder,
            EmpId = displayOrderTable[y.DisplayOrder],
        }).ToList();
```

This will run in O(N+N) = O(N) time as opposed to O(N^2) (using for in for).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the equivalent of your code using just LINQ

```
var empCompList = compList
    .GroupBy(c => c.GroupId)
    .SelectMany((g, i) => g.Select(c => new EmpComp
    {
        EmpCompId = c.CompId,
        EmpCompName = c.CompName,
        GroupId = c.GroupId,
        EmpId = i + 1
    }))
    .ToList();
```

The key point is using the [SelectMany overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549142(v=vs.110).aspx) which receives source element and index.